# In Apps Script, How to change the value inside dropdown dynamically inside CardService?

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown, add-on

I have a problem in changing the value of a dropdown in AppsScript. I actully need help in changing the data/list inside a dropdown based on another dropdown's selected value/item.

My question is, ***how can we add/change the values in the destination dropdown at runtime even after it is been initialized with other values at the very starting point of this side panel creation.***

**Edit-** Here is a screen shot of dropdowns. In this, **"From"** is the `"origin"` and **"To"** is `"destination"`

[image: dropdown_visuals]

What I want is - e.g. if in `origin` dropdown, user has selected "French" then in the `destination` dropdown, it should only show "Finnish" and "Frisian". How can I achieve this?

Following is the code I am using to create the dropdowns in apps script side panel. This code is adding the items of `LM` constant in both the dropdowns.

```
const LM = [
    { text: 'Finnish', val: 'fi' },
    { text: 'French', val: 'fr' },
    { text: 'Frisian', val: 'fy' },
    { text: 'Galician', val: 'gl' },
    { text: 'Georgian', val: 'ka' },
    { text: 'German', val: 'de' },
     -----
     -----
     -----
  ]

function createSelectionCard(){

   builder.addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(generateLanguagesDropdown('origin', 'From: ', DEFAULT_ORIGIN_LAN)
    .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('onSourceLanguageChange'))));

   builder.addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(generateLanguagesDropdown('destination', 'To: ', destinationLanguage)));
}

function generateLanguagesDropdown(fieldName, fieldTitle, previousSelected) {
  var selectionInput = CardService.newSelectionInput().setTitle(fieldTitle)
    .setFieldName(fieldName)
    .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN);

  LM.forEach((language, index, array) => {
    selectionInput.addItem(language.text, language.val, language.val == previousSelected);
  })

  return selectionInput;
}
```

I am getting the selected item in `onSourceLanguageChange()` event method. Now based on this selection, I need to change the values in dropdown *"destination"*.

The main question is, ***how can we add/change the values in the destination dropdown at runtime even after it is been initialized with other values at the very starting point of this side panel creation.***

Comment: "What I want is - e.g. in origin dropdown, user has selected "French" then in the destination dropdown, it should only show "Finnish" and "Frisian". How can I achieve this?" Do you have this from -> to list anywhere?

Comment: @Aerials Yes, I have this list. the main question of mine is, how can we add/change the values in the destination dropdown even after it is been initialized with other values at the very starting point of this side panel creation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen on the client-side (using JS in your HTML) for when the user selects an option in the source drop-down. And send a signal using [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to execute a function on the server-side which changes the options in your destination drop-down.

Have a read at the [client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) articles in the documentation.

Notice how they serve HTML with a `<script>` which contains a function "google.script.run" which allows to call functions in the server side.

---

#### UPDATE:

You may not use [HTML/CSS or client-side scripting](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/gsuite-restrictions#_use_htmlcss_or_client-side_scripting) with Add-Ons. You should use [Actions](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/actions) to have interaction with the user.

Comment: I don't have client-server thing for my application or if I have it by default, I m not sure where I can get this. I am creating a gsuit addon. There I can only interact with a json file and some .gs files, that's it. How this HTML and <script> things comes into the picture? Btw, Thanks for answering.

Comment: I'm afraid its not possible I updated my answer to reflect so. Its one of the restrictions here: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/gsuite-restrictions

Comment: @TanmayBairagi for interactions you should use Actions. I updates my asnwer to show it.